# How do I SSH from a Docker container to a remote server

Tags: postgresql, docker, ssh

I am building a docker image off postgres image, and I would like to seed it with some data.

I am following the [initialization-scripts](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/postgres/#initialization-scripts) section of the documentation.

But the problem I am facing now, is that my initialisation scripts needs to ssh to a remote database and dumb data from there. Basically something like this:

```
ssh remote.host "pg_dump -U user -d somedb" > some.sql
```

but this fails with the error that `ssh: command not found`

Question now is, in general, how do I ssh from a docker container to a remote server. In this case, specifically how do I ssh from a docker container to a remote database server as part of the initialisation step of seeding a postgres database?

Comment: An explanation for the downvote and vote for closure would be appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule you don't do things this way.  Typical Docker images contain *only* the server they're running and some core tools, but network clients like `ssh` or `curl` generally aren't part of this.  In the particular case of `ssh`, securely managing the credentials required is also tricky (not impossible, but not obvious).

In your particular case, I might rearrange things so that your scripts didn't have the hard assumption the database was running locally.  Provision an empty database container, then run your script *from the host* targeting that empty database.  It may even work to set the `PGHOST` and `PGPORT` environment variables to point to your host machine's host name and the port you publish the database interface on, and then run that script unmodified.

Looking closer at that specific command, you also may find it better to set up a cron job to run that specific database dump and put the contents somewhere.  Then a developer can get a snapshot of the data without having to make a connection to the live database server, and you can limit the number of people who will have access.  Once you have this dump file, you can use the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` mechanism to cause it to be loaded at first startup time.